# Reference for convergent nets as continuous functions from $D\cup\{\infty\}$

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, continuity, nets

If we have any [directed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) $(D,\le)$ then we can add a point $\infty\notin D$ and then consider the topology on $C(D)=D\cup\{\infty\}$ such that all points of $D$ are isolated and the local base at $\infty$ consists of all "upper sets" $\langle d,\infty\rangle=\{\infty\}\cup\{d'\in D; d'\ge d\}$. (I.e., the topology is given by the base<sup>1</sup> ​$\mathcal B=\{\{d\}; d\in D\}\cup\{\langle d,\infty\rangle; d\in D\}$.)

Then we can get the following observation:<sup>2</sup>

**Fact:** Let $X$ be a topological space, $\ell\in X$ and $x\colon D\to X$ be a [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)). Then the net $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ converges to $\ell$ if and only if the map $\overline x\colon C(D)\to X$ given by
$$\overline x(d)=
\begin{cases} 
x_d,&\text{if }x\in D,\\
\ell,&\text{if }x=\infty.\\
\end{cases}$$
is continuous.

In the other words, we have characterization of the convergence $x_d\to\ell$ using the map given by $\overline x|_D=x$ and $x(\infty)=\ell$.

**Question.** Are there some textbooks which explicitly mention this observation? I.e., where this topology on $D\cup\{\infty\}$ is defined and the relation between convergence of nets continuity of functions $C(D)\to X$ is mentioned?

Although this observation is rather trivial, I consider it worth mentioning when I am introducing convergence of nets to students.

- I have an example of topological space which is tightly linked with convergence of nets.
- It is often (if not always) useful to have several possible viewpoints of the same notion.
- When proving various results about nets I can point to corresponding results on continuity. (Characterization of convergence in product corresponds to characterization of continuity of a function into a product space - in both cases it suffices to consider each coordinate separately. If we have a convergent net $x\colon D\to X$ then for a continuous function $f\colon X\to Y$ we have a convergent net $f\circ x\colon D\to Y$. This corresponds to composition of continuous maps $\overline{f\circ x}=f\circ\overline x$.)
- When defining subnet, I have another directed net $E$ and a cofinal map $h\colon E\to D$. Then I can explain cofinality also in the way: This means that $h(e)\to\infty$, if we consider $(h(e))_{e\in E}$ as a net in the topological space $C(D)$.

Since this observation is rather trivial, it must have been noticed by many people. That's the reason why I was a bit surprised that I did not notice this observation mentioned in various textbooks and introductory text that I checked.

---

**Remark:** We could get a similar result for $\mathcal F$-limits. I.e., if we have a function $f\colon M\to X$ and a filter $\mathcal F$ on $M$, then we can define when $\ell\in X$ is an $\mathcal F$-limit of the function $f$. And if we choose appropriate topology on the set $C(\mathcal F)$ on the set $M\cup\{\infty\}$ then we get analogous observation. (In this case the topology is $\mathcal T=\{\{x\}; x\in M\}\cup \{\{\infty\}\cup F; F\in\mathcal F\}$. If you take a filterbase instead of a filter, you get a base for the topology.) However, there are only a few books in general topology that actually consider convergence of filters in this generality - some references can be found here: [Where has this common generalization of nets and filters been written down?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1568548).

I am mentioning this here mainly because the observation for nets which I mentioned above is a special case of the observation for filters. (For every directed sets, we have a filterbase $\{\langle d,\infty); d\in D\}$ on the set $D$. For the filter obtained from this filterbase, the notion of $\mathcal F$-limit coincides with the usual definition of a limit of a net.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It is easy to check that this system indeed forms a [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)). Whenever we have $\infty\in\langle d_1,\infty\rangle \cap \langle d_2,\infty\rangle$ then there is an $d\in D$ with $d\ge d_1,d_2$, which means that $\infty\in\langle d,\infty\rangle\subseteq \langle d_1,\infty\rangle \cap \langle d_2,\infty\rangle$. And the analogous condition is trivially true for isolated points.

<sup>2</sup>Proof of this fact is basically just rewriting the definitions.

Comment: Do you know tha treatment of convergence in Preuss Topologische Räume I? It's even more general and IMO quite elegant. No mention of your $D$ though. For sequences we have one space to deal with and for nets a huge class of such spaces (characterised by being almost discrete, i.e. having exactly one non-isolated point).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I wasn't sure which book you mean here. I did not find a book by G. Preuss with this title. (There is a book by H. Herrlich called Topologie I: Topologische Räume - but I do not have access to that one.) I left [more details in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2021/11/27).

Comment: Yeah it’s Herrlich. I have it on my shelves; part 2 on Uniforme Räume too

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try to find out whether I can get hold of it.

Comment: Slovaks can probably read German pretty well (and Russian too). Handy in maths too.